# mongoose docker CRUD not working despite successful connection

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoose, crud

I am learning docker and creating a simple web app to add two numbers. I want to save and fetch the operations in MongoDB

I created my own Dockerfiles for mongodb and node and also a docker-compose file. Mongoose is able to connect with my MongoDB container.

When I try to create a document, I am unable to find it via mongoose or via mongo shell. I also created a document in the same db via mongo shell and I am still not able to find it.

#### MongoDB dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y wget gnupg
RUN wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc | apt-key add -

RUN echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 multiverse" | \
        tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list

RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y mongodb-org=5.0.2 mongodb-org-database=5.0.2 mongodb-org-server=5.0.2  \
        mongodb-org-shell=5.0.2 mongodb-org-mongos=5.0.2 mongodb-org-tools=5.0.2
EXPOSE 27017
CMD ["/usr/bin/mongod", "-f", "/etc/mongod.conf"]
```

#### Node Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y curl

RUN mkdir /usr/local/nvm
ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION 14.18.1

RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash \
        && source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
        && nvm install v$NODE_VERSION

ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH

RUN mkdir /usr/app

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY . /usr/app
RUN npm install

RUN npm install -g nodemon

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["nodemon", "index.js"]
```

#### Docker Compose File

```
version: "3.9"

services: 
  db:
    image: db
    build: 
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.mongodb
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - /home/rohit/Downloads/mongodb_data:/var/lib/mongodb

  app:
    image: app
    build: 
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.node
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes: 
      - /home/rohit/github_repos/node-react-jenkins-docker/:/usr/app
    depends_on:
      - db
```

#### Node app.js

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
mongoose.connect('mongodb://db:27017/test', {useNewUrlParser: true})
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });

const testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  num1: Number,
  num2: Number,
  result: Number,
});

const Sum = mongoose.model('sum', testSchema);

const sum = new Sum({
  num1: 5,
  num2: 3,
  result: 8,
});
sum.save();

Sum.find((err, sums) => {
  console.log(sums);
});

app.get('/', function (req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.post('/', function (req, res){
  var num1 = Number(req.body.num1);
  var num2 = Number(req.body.num2);
  var result = num1 + num2;
  res.send('The result of calculation is ' + result);
});

module.exports = app
```

I executed `docker-compose build` followed by `docker-compose up`

I am able to access localhost:3000 on my browser successfully but I do not see the console logs.

I have mounted my working directory so that any changes I make locally is picked up by the node container.

`docker container ls` gives

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS             PORTS                                           NAMES
0f98d3a819b2   app       "nodemon index.js"       About an hour ago   Up About an hour   0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, :::3000->3000/tcp       node-react-jenkins-docker_app_1
d2a4a2ca229a   db        "/usr/bin/mongod -f …"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp, :::27017->27017/tcp   node-react-jenkins-docker_db_1
```

#### Tried accessing the mongo shell in the container

`docker container exec -it node-react-jenkins-docker_db_1 mongo`

```
> show dbs
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.000GB
test    0.000GB
> db
test
> show collections
sums
> db.sums.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "num1" : 2, "num2" : 1, "result" : 3 }
>
```

It shows the document I created manually, but I cannot access this through Sum.find() in app.js. I also do not see the document that should have been created by app.js when it runs successfully.

Please find the complete repository at [GitHub](https://github.com/rohitsrao/node-react-jenkins-docker/tree/mongooose-test)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own issue after speaking with an experienced developer. Turns out the bindIp in the mongod.conf file needed to be set to 0.0.0.0 and then it starts working. Sharing incase anyone else runs into the same issue.